# Standard container re-allocation multipliers across popular toolchains

Tags: c++, implementation, containers

Containers like `std::basic_string` and `std::vector` perform automatic re-allocations when internal capacity runs out. The standard specifies that, after a re-allocation, `.capacity() >= .size()`.

What are some of the *actual* multipliers used by mainstream toolchains when performing re-allocations?

---

**Update**

So far, I have:

> Dinkumware: 1.5 (ships with MSVS and possibly ICC)
>
> GNU libstdc++: 2 (ships with GCC and possibly ICC)
>
> RW/Apache stdcxx: 1.618 (aka φ)
>
> STLport: 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New answer for an old question.

Rationale:  The answer can be answered programatically, and with online compilers, relatively easily.  Here is a program that can help you answer this question:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#   include <cxxabi.h>
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string
type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own
           (
#ifndef _MSC_VER
                abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr,
                                           nullptr, nullptr),
#else
                nullptr,
#endif
                std::free
           );
    std::string r = own != nullptr ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}

template <class C>
void
test()
{
    C c;
    std::cout << type_name<C>() << ":\n";
    std::size_t c0 = c.capacity();
    std::cout << "    Initial capacity is " << c0 << '\n';
    c.resize(c0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        c.push_back(typename C::value_type{});
        std::size_t c1 = c.capacity();
        if (c0 != 0)
        {
            float f = static_cast<float>(c1)/c0;
            std::cout << "    growth factor appears to be " << f << '\n';
        }
        c0 = c1;
        c.resize(c0);
    }
}

int
main()
{
    test<std::vector<int>>();
    test<std::string>();
}
```

Most of the complexity is a bit unnecessary as it is just to get `type_name` working.

**libstdc++:**

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/njaIG2uiR2vlCLZz

appears to answer a solid 2 for both vector and string.

**VS:**

http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net

is very close to 1.5 for both vector and string.

**libc++**

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mXshrLJHgNuvE1mD

is very close to 2 for both vector and string.

Note that this program also tells you what the short string buffer is for `string`:  15 for both libstdc++ and VS, and 22 for libc++.

Answer (score 4):

Dinkumware STL (shipped with Visual Studio) uses a 1.5 multiplier, Gcc uses 2. I cannot really tell for the rest, but I think those are the most often used numbers. (IIRC, I read once that *most* implementations used 2)

As a side comment, you are correctly calling it a *multiplier* since the standard requires the growth to be (at least) geometrical.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance that you can provide references for those numbers?

Comment: BTW, It's Meyers (among others, I'm sure), who says that "most implementations" use 2. It seems to be a popular thing to repeat, and a lot of people seem to think it's always the case, or even that it's standard.

Comment: @Tomalak, the gcc I manually inspected it in the headers. Basically it does `new_size = size + max( 1, size() );`. As of visual studio, I heard it in a recent Channel9 video from Stephan T. Lavavej. In GCC, the actual function for a vector that determines the new size is `_M_check_len( size_type, const char* )`, in `stl_vector.h`

Comment: @David: Thanks for this. Will keep this question open; would like to see whether anyone can come up with more examples from other toolchains and versions. :)

Comment: BTW, it is not *that* hard to get the numbers from the headers, it just takes a bit of inspection and getting used to the weird identifiers in the library, but the implementations of containers like vectors should not be too complex to interpret. (I know it is not trivial, been there, done that)

Comment: @David: Oh I realise that, but someone may have a to-hand table of values from multiple toolchains across multiple versions, saving a whole load of work. :)