# By how much does vector::resize increase capacity?

Tags: c++, resize, stdvector, capacity

As far as I know the C++ standard does not specify exactly how vector capacity is increased when vector::resize requires an increase.  But is there a "typical" implementation?

Specifically: I don't know how large my vector needs to be.  Further, the elements come in random order.  So for each element I have this:

```
if ( index >= vector.size() ) {
    vector.resize ( index + 1 );
}
vector.at ( index ) = element;
```

If the elements come in increasing index order, will the vector capacity be increased by one for each call to resize (in a typical implementation)?  I'm hoping not...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard container re-allocation multipliers across popular toolchains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404489/standard-container-re-allocation-multipliers-across-popular-toolchains)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: This is a different question. There are no guaranteed asymptotics for repeated `resize()`s.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's exactly the same question. "By how much will my container's capacity increase in implementation?"

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Not quite: That question concerns `push_back`, and `push_back` has mandatory complexity guarantees (i.e. amortized constant) -- this in turn forces the implementation to grow the storage geometrically. There's no comparable requirement that would affect the `resize()` situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's a factor of an answer, not of the question.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I'm not sure - the question asks for "the actual multipliers", but what I'm saying is that there's no connection between `resize()` and any "multipliers", since there's no requirement that allocation induced by `resize()` follow any particular scheme. That's a different context, non?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, whatever. :) I've decided it could go either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard makes no guarantees about the asymptotics of repeated calls to `resize()`. It is entirely feasible that the container will simply grow the capacity to precisely the required target size. In fact, this would probably be the *desirable* behaviour (i.e. the least wasteful) in the majority of standard use cases for `resize()` (e.g. where it's just used *once*).

If you're worried, just implement your own geometric growth:

```
if (index + 1 > v.size()
{
    if (v.capacity() < index + 1)
    {
        v.reserve(2 * (index + 1));   // I had 2 * capacity() here first, but
                                      // I think this version is better
    }
    v.resize(index + 1);
}
```

Comment: And, after inserting all items, OP could shrink the vector again to save memory, if that's an issue at all.

Comment: @arne: [Not guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829018/can-we-rely-on-the-reduce-capacity-trick).

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: What about `v.resize(v.size())`? I suspect it's not guaranteed to reduce the size, but it may.

Comment: I think you're pretty much *guaranteed* that nobody shrinks the size, ever, with the possible exception of `shrink_to_fit()`, isn't that so?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: OK, I see. That's definitely something to keep in mind with memory intensive applications...

Comment: `v.resize(v.size())` is guaranteed not to relocate the existing elements. There's pretty much no way it can free any memory since the `Alloc` interface that vector uses to allocate memory doesn't have a `realloc` function. Prior to C++11, the idiom to shrink a vector was `vector<something>(v).swap(v);`, but that's obsolete now because it copies all the members, it can't move them.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, what `resize` does exactly depends on your implementation (and may change between different versions of the same implementation).

On compliant implementations, `push_back` causes the capacity to double each time it has to be increased, and this has to do with the amortized complexity of a series of `push_back`'s. If it were to increase the capacity by 1 each time, the complexity for `N` additions would be `O(N^2)`, whereas if `push_back` doubles the capacity each time, the complexity for the same series of additions would only be `O(N)` - a big deal.

As for you question - if you know in advance the maximal `index`, just pre-allocate. Otherwise, I think you're better off with `std::map`:

```
map<int, T> M;
for (...) {
  M[index] = element;
}
```

This will have complexity `O(N log N)` for `N` additions, but won't waste memory on indices which do not have corresponding `element`'s.

Comment: Note that the capacity doesn't have to double, any constant strictly larger than 1 will do.

Comment: unless your stroed objects are rather large, map will waste more memory (each map entry has overhead of a few pointers, then add overhead of the allocator).