# Is it guaranteed that std::vector default construction does not call new?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

According to [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) a simple `std::vector<T> vec;` creates an emtpy container (default constructor). Does this guarantee that there is no dynamic memory allocation?
Or may an implementation chose to reserve some memory?

I known that, for this empty constructor, there is no construction of the type `T` since C++11.
However, I wonder, if there is also a guarantee that nothing is allocated on heap. I.e. that the above line is just a few `nullptr` on stack/member.

I tested it with vc140, where it is indeed free of dynamic allocations.

Comment: Since the constructor is `noexcept`, doesn't that guarantee it (otherwise it could throw `std::bad_alloc`)?

Comment: @Quentin the constructor can catch such exception and carry on.

Comment: Looks like a duplication of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036474/when-vectors-are-allocated-do-they-use-memory-on-the-heap-or-the-stack

Comment: @Quentin just because the constructor is noexcept doesn't mean that it couldn't *try* to opportunistically  allocate some memory, catch the bad_alloc and just refrain from allocating anything if `new` throws. noexcept just means the constructor won't throw itself - it doesn't prevent it from calling stuff that throws as long as it handles the exception.

Comment: Fair enough. --

Comment: @LukePurnell Its not a duplicate. Your linked question is about where elements and header information go. My question is about WHEN memory for the elements is allocated.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: @MartinBonner a dynamic allocation is expensive and if there are tons of objects creating empty vectors in their constructors for example in a `vector<vector<T>> x` it might hurt. Especially, if many of those will stay empty their entire lifetime.

Comment: Right.  So it is a performance issue, rather than correctness issue.  The standard tends to leave things like that to "quality if implementation".  The only exception is big-O stuff, but this isn't big-O: the time taken to construct vectors will still be O(number-of-vectors) - this is just about the constant.  (Admittedly, the constant may change by a factor of 1000, but ...)

Comment: Also related [Is the compiler allowed to optimize out heap memory allocations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31873616/1708801)

Comment: @MartinBonner also notable, it helps creating containers that can be instantiated on incomplete types

Comment: On MSVC (2019) in Debug, there will be an allocation, but not in Release.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Does this guarantee that there is no dynamic memory allocation?

No. It is however quite typical that an implementation doesn't allocate memory. I haven't seen a standard library implementation that does.

> Or may an implementation chose to reserve some memory?

It may, but that's atypical.

> I known that, for this empty constructor, there is no construction of the type `T` since C++11

Also prior to C++11.

Comment: The standard offers no guarantees of course, but it is quite likely that the default constructor will not allocate - doing an allocation would pessimize the "default construct + reserve" construct (it will either have to do *two* allocations, or will end up allocating too much memory).

Comment: I think it's important to mention that msvc will, in debug, allocate on the default constructor of `std::vector`. It does so as well for `std::string` and a few other containers. This happens when `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` is set to non-0 (1 or 2) and it enables several runtime checks. The default value of `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` is 2 in debug and 0 in release. You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/iterator-debug-level?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 30):

std library is part of the C++ language.

Almost any call to any std library class or function could do pathological and insane things.  But the same is true of `int x=7;` -- the standard is not written to defend against frankly hostile C++ implementations, which includes the std library.

That being said, the zero argument constructor to std vector is noexcept.  This means it is *intended* to not allocate.  A hostile implementation is free to allocate, catch any errors, and proceed regardless of if the allocation succeeded.  A hostile implementation is also free to count to 47 trillion, run some FFT on random data, spin up a neural network and train it against Shakespeare, compose some sonnets, then proceed as if nothing happened.  The standard has nothing to say on the inobservable poetry composition of any operation in C++; so long as the action has no observable (within the abstract machine) side effects, the standard has no opinion.

In practice there is no reason for `std::vector<T>()` to allocate, and no later operation on it can assume it allocated.  I could see an instrumented build allocating some lifetime tracking token to enforce iterator invalidation errors, but that would only be enabled in debug with extra flags (e.g. `-DCMP_JUN17`).

Worry more about poetry than a call to new.

Comment: This explanation is oddly amusing.

Comment: Is `CMP_JUN17` an obscure reference that went over my head?

Comment: @Quentin Compare with jun 17th, a summer's day

Comment: Keep in mind that even those hostile implementations are required to adhere to the complexity requirements ^^

Comment: @PlasmaHH That just means the length of the sonnet (and training set of the neural network) cannot vary with N (or, at least, cannot increase without bound).

Comment: @Yakk: indeed, and having implement some parts of the evil stdlib I can tell you it bites you often. Haven't found a proper way to store strings backwards yet and adhere to the requirements.

Comment: @CortAmmon I mentioned that explicitly in the 2nd to last paragraph?

Comment: @Yakk Ahh, you're right.  Deleting the comment.  I thought that paragraph was intended to be tongue in cheek with the `-DCMP_JUN17`, when I was thinking more along the lines of Microsoft's STL implementation, which allocates a LOT in debug mode, without any obscure flags at all.

Comment: @CortAmmon Well, `-D_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL =0` to turn it off in MSVC.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee.

A counter example that I just hit (and which led me to this post) is MSVC2017's STL implementation, if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0.