# Why these results show there is no need to using reserve in vector?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, stdvector

I wrote the code below to measure the time taken to pushback integers `1000k` times without using reserve and with reserving. The result was not what I wanted.

All the tests are performed on my Samsung ativtap7 having a core i5 @1.8 Ghz processor, 4 GB RAM and VS2018 C++ Compiler running under Windows 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Stopwatch.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Stopwatch myWatch;
    //pushback 1000k times without reserve
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "try " << i + 1 << endl;
        myWatch.Start();
        vector<int> vec1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            vec1.push_back(i);
        }
        myWatch.End();
        myWatch.LookElapsedTime();

        //pushback 1000k times with reserve
        myWatch.Start();
        vector<int> vec2(1000000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            vec2.push_back(i);
        }

        myWatch.End();
        myWatch.LookElapsedTime();
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected results that show the meaningful difference between using reserve and not using reserve but actual results didn't match my expectations.

below is the results.

```
try 1
1.51118(sec)
1.46981(sec)

try 2 
1.43074(sec)
1.4381(sec)

try 3
1.4428(sec)
1.46196(sec)

try 4
1.41903(sec)
1.43688(sec)

try 5
1.47544(sec)
1.558(sec)

try 6
1.47474(sec)
1.45484(sec)

try 7
1.47731(sec)
1.5908(sec)

try 8
1.77192(sec)
1.72018(sec)

try 9
1.56832(sec)
1.447(sec)

try 10
1.43659(sec)
1.43572(sec)
```

I want to know why this happened.

Comment: What is `Stopwatch`? Share its implementation as well!

Comment: You’re not `reserve`ing anything. Compare the sizes of your vectors.

Comment: Which compilation command do you use, and does it include -O3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As JeJo has mentioned, you are not using reserve. You are allocating a vector with 1000000 integers, and then go on and add more 1000000 integers to it.

But even when fixing the code and using `reserve`, things are not as good as one might expect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  //pushback 1000k times without reserve
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      cout << "try " << i+1 << endl;
      auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      vector<int> vec1;
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
          vec1.push_back(i);
        }

      auto finish = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto passed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(finish-start);
      cout << passed.count() << " us\n";
      start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

      //pushback 1000k times with reserve
      vector<int> vec2;
      vec2.reserve(1000000);
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
          vec2.push_back(i);
        }

      finish = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      passed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(finish-start);
      cout << passed.count() << " us\n";
      cout << endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

With the results:

```
try 1
6313 us
3478 us

try 2
1775 us
1412 us

try 3
1996 us
1551 us

try 4
2054 us
1579 us

try 5
1936 us
1427 us

try 6
1647 us
1504 us

try 7
1902 us
1754 us

try 8
1893 us
1952 us

try 9
1655 us
1874 us

try 10
2019 us
1736 us
```

The first try has a x2 speed-up with reserve, but the other tries do not show a big difference.  The reason is that once the memory blocks of appropriate sizes have been allocated, they are being cached by C++. This way, these blocks are fast to reuse in the next try. Most C++ implementations will cache these block (either through malloc's implementation or otherwise), so the next time the block is required it is reused very quickly.

This simple caching of new/delete blocks is not as effective in the real world as it is effective in micro-benchmarks. In the real word there is a lot more going on with the heap, making the cache less effective for reserve-less vectors.

Comment: It's also because copying big blocks of `int`s is fast on modern hardware. If the elements were of class type, requiring non-trivial copy/move assignment every time the vector grows, the difference would likely be far more pronounced.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I totally agree. With complicated objects, the heap part (of the reallocation) no longer dominates times. With complicated objects, the number of constructions/destructions/copying starts to dominate. In that case, the difference becomes much bigger. It should be about 2x-4x on systems that reallocate in multiples of 2, and 3x-6x on systems that reallocate in multiples of 1.5

Comment: And, for anyone visiting and now wondering which systems those are: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672798/560648

Answer (score 14):

You have not [reserv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) ed memory at all. In your second vector

```
vector<int> vec2(1000000);
```

this means, allocate and initialize `1000000` integers with `0`. You need instead

```
vector<int> vec2;
vec2.reserve(1000000);
```

See a benchmark done using *quick-bench.com*. It is clear now that **reserving matters**.

**([See online](http://quick-bench.com/BVv5dhET19XtknFQsndKfMwuLtc))**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's because neither vector preallocates memory for `push_back`s

In `vec2`, you create a vector of 1000000 elements and then push another 1000000 elements.

If you'd check `size()` on both vectors, you'd see that `vec1.size() == 1000000` and `vec2.size() == 2000000`

If you want to use `reserve` mechanism, you should do the following:

```
vector<int> vec2;
vec2.reserve(1000000);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    vec2.push_back(i);
}
```

Or alternatively

```
vector<int> vec2(1000000);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    vec2[i] = i;
}
```